# Deduct type of which other type is dependent

Tags: c++, templates

I have this situation:

```
#include <vector>

template<typename T, typename U = T>
U f(T data) {
    return U();
}

int main() {
    std::vector<int> vec = {1,2,3};
    return f<std::vector<int>, int>(vec);
}
```

`T` is always a templated type and `U` is always the type that `T` depends. Is there a way to get `U` from `T` in order to don't explicit `int` twice in `f` call?

I've tried the following, but It didn't work:

```
#include <vector>

template<template<class> class T, class U>
U f(T<U> data) {
    return U();
}

int main() {
    std::vector<int> vec = {1,2,3};
    return f<std::vector, int>(vec);
}
```

Comment: What error did you get for that last snippet?

Comment: you can use `typename T::value_type` instead of U

Comment: What compiler (including version and flags) do you use?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue here is `std::vector` doesn't have just one template parameter.  It also has a parameter for the allocator type.  To get around that you can add another template parameter, or just use a variadic template template parameter like

```
template<template<class...> class T, class U>
U f(T<U> data) {
    return U();
}
```

which will work with

```
return f<std::vector, int>(vec);
```

or even better

```
return f(vec);
```

Do note that this behavior has been changed in C++17.  With [DR: Matching of template template-arguments excludes compatible templates](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0522r0.html) they relaxed the rules and

```
template<template<class> class T, class U>
U f(T<U> data) {
    return U();
}
```

will work with gcc in C++17 mode and clang in C++17 with `-frelaxed-template-template-args` enabled.

Comment: OP's code works for me without any changes (both on GCC with `-std=c++17` ang Clang with `-std=c++17 -frelaxed-template-template-args`). It seems to be well-formed since C++17.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I do recall something about allowing defaulted parameters to not be specified in template template parameters.  I'll try and see if I can find the paper when I get a minute.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I've found the paper and added it to the answer.